# Using JSOUP How to Extract all elements from one tag & add in another tag?

Tags: java, jsoup, java-11

I need to set `<a>` tag to all `<h2>` tags in the document. Document contains few `<h2>` tags with `<a>` tags & few are without `<a>` tag.

I need to:

1. If `<h2>` has `<a>` tag then, check if it has `id`. if it's not there then set the `id`
2. If `<h2>` tag donesn't have `<a>` tag then add `<a>` tag in `<h2>`

e.g. if original HTML is like this:
Case 1:

```
<h2><a href="#headingABC"><span style="color:#009bd2;">My Heading ABC</span></a></h2>
```

Then, change it to (add id):

```
<h2><a id="heading1" href="#headingXYZ"><span style="color:#009bd2;">My Heading ABC</span></a></h2>
```

case 2:

```
<h2><span style="color:#009bd2;">My Heading ABC</span></h2>
```

Then, change it to (add a tag by moving all elements in `h2` inside `a`):

```
<h2><a id="heading1"><span style="color:#009bd2;">My Heading ABC</span></a></h2>
```

How can I achieve this using JSOUP in Java (version 11).

Comment: Your question is almost impossible to understand because you have written HTML in it, but you have not surrounded that HTML with backticks. I changed the first one for you, so you can see what I mean. It's the difference between the HTML being displayed in the question and not displayed at all: _I need to set `<a>` tag..._

Comment: Also, what have you tried? Show us your Jsoup attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Elements elements = doc.select("h2");
for (Element element : elements) {
    Element firstChild = element.child(0);
    if (firstChild.tagName().equals("a") && firstChild.attr("id").isEmpty()) {
        firstChild.attr("id", "heading1");
    } else {
        firstChild.wrap("<a id=\"heading1\">");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. this solves my issue. I added code to detect if H2 has any child.